# Aeron publication suddenly stops message transmission

Tags: aeron

I have the stream which suddenly (after number of successfully transmitted messages) stops sending|receiving messages.

The output of AeronStat for it is:

```
47 : 8,452,864 - pub-pos (sampled): 9 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100
48 : 8,519,104 - pub-lmt: 9 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100
49 : 130,496 - snd-pos: 9 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100
50 : 131,072 - snd-lmt: 9 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100
51 : 0 - snd-bpe: 9 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100
52 : 130,496 - rcv-hwm: 10 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100
53 : 130,496 - rcv-pos: 10 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100
54 : 0 - sub-pos: 2 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100 @0
55 : 130,496 - sub-pos: 8 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100 @0
```

It looks like there is relatively small snd-lmt which prevets the transmission. Is my understanding correct? How can I change snd-lmt ?
And also what does it mean when I have two sub-pos entries for one channnel in AeronStat output e.g.:

```
54 : 0 - sub-pos: 2 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100 @0
55 : 130,496 - sub-pos: 8 -813703616 1 aeron:udp?endpoint=localhost:40100 @0
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your termBufferLength?  Are you using `tryClaim`?

Answer (score 4):

Two `sub-pos` counter values indicates you have two separate subscriptions to the same stream on that media driver. The publication is likely to be experiencing back-pressure because of the subscriptions is not advancing as it is likely not being polled.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I've already figured that out and fixed the situation.